# Simulating multiple Poisson processes

Tags: python, math

I have N processes and a different Poisson rate for each. I would like to simulate arrival times from all N processes.  If N =1 I can do this

```
t = 0
N = 1
for i in range(1,10):
   t+= random.expovariate(15)
   print N, t
```

However if I have `N = 5`  and a list of rates

```
rates =  [10,1,15,4,2]
```

I would like somehow for the loop to output the arrival times of all N processes in the right order.  That is I would still like only two numbers per line (the ID of the process and the arrival time) but globally sorted by arrival time.

I could just make N lists and merge them afterwards but I would like the arrival times to be outputted in the right order in the first place.

**Update.** One problem is that if you just sample a fixed number of arrivals from each process, you get only early times from the high rate processes. So I think I need to sample from a fixed time interval for each process so the number of samples varies depending on the rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

```
import random
import itertools

def arrivalGenerator(rate):
    t = 0
    while True:
        t += random.expovariate(rate)
        yield t

rates = [10, 1, 15, 4, 2]
t = [(i, 0) for i in range(0, len(rates))]
arrivals = []
for i in range(len(rates)):
    t = 0
    generator = arrivalGenerator(rates[i])
    arrivals += [(i, arrival) \
                 for arrival in itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t < 100, generator)]


sorted_arrivals = sorted(arrivals, key=lambda x: x[1])
for arrival in sorted_arrivals:
    print arrival[0], arrival[1]
```

Note that your initial logic was generating a fixed number of arrivals for each process. What you really want is a specific time window, and to keep generating for a given process until you exceed that time window.

Comment: Thanks but each line should have just two numbers. The ID of the process (a number between 0 and N-1) and the latest arrival time for it.

Comment: Oh, okay, but in sorted order by arrival time?

Comment: Yes that is right. The idea being that those IDs with low rates won't appear much at all compared to those with high rates.

Comment: @felix: I got you. Give me a minute, that's easily derivable from what we already have.

Comment: Thanks but it still gives me an output like [(4, 0.028766483899779847), (3, 0.05851372490609404), (0, 0.11221239706883575), (2, 0.3222644557142115), (1, 0.7791031448265548)]  . I would really like only two numbers per line.

Comment: @felix: Please see the edit, but in the future, you really have to show a minimum amount of effort.

Comment: Oh thanks. The problem is that I don't see how to do it without printing the whole thing out and then sorting. The latest version stil doesn't print out the arrivals in order. Sorry if it looks like I am not trying.

Comment: Wait, do you want them globally sorted, or just per each iteration through the loop? Your question is not clearly specified.

Comment: Globally sorted. I'll clarify the question now.

Comment: Again, easy enough from what we already have. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks again. I must have got something wrong as I expect the IDs with high rates to appear more often than those with low rates throughout.  However with rates = [100, 1, 1, 1, 1] I get lots of ID 0 at the start but then not many after.

Comment: @felix: You need to change the logic for how you're generating the arrivals. You're generating a fixed number for each ID. Instead, you should pick a time window, and for each process, generate for that process until you step outside the window. Make sense?

Comment: Oh I see the problem.  Because we are always sampling ten arrivals from each process the ones with high rates only show the ones near time 0.  I think I need to sample from a time interval instead to get what I want.

Comment: See, what you're doing right now is you are generating the arrival times for ten of each of the processes. It sounds like what you want is, for some given time window, keep generating arrivals for each process until they exceed that time window? Does that make sense? Do you see the difference?

Comment: @felix: That's exactly it. Do you need my help with that?

Comment: That's great, thanks!  I do wonder if there was some way to do it without sorting but I am more than happy with the solution you came up  with.

Comment: @felix: Note that sorting is not completely necessary in the following sense. The arrival lists for each process come out sorted. You could write a merge routine to just merge these lists together (rather than sort the whole concatenated list of all the arrivals). That'd be linear in the number of arrivals, instead of `O(n log n)` (`n` is the number of arrivals). Make sense?

Comment: The answer is to simulate at the sum of the rates and then label the arrival times as they arrive in order according to the distribution of the rates. That is choose ID x independently with prob rate[x]/(sum rates) .

Answer (score 1):

Following http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-PP-NSPP.pdf I think there is a more efficient answer.

You do roughly:

```
total_rate = sum(rates)
probabilities = [ r/total_rate for r in rates ]

arrivals = []
t = 0
while t < T:
   t += random.expovariate(total_rate)
   i = weighted_random(probabilities)
   arrivals += (i, t)
```

This method eliminates the need to keep coroutine state around for a large number of different arrival processes. There's just a single "net" arrival process. The distribution will be the same.

Note that I have not given an implementation for weighted_random above, but I assume my intention is clear. It is left as an exercise for the reader ;-) -- or see e.g. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python.

You can also do:

```
arrivals = []
t = 0
while t < T:
    dt_list = [ random.expovariate(r) for r in rates ]
    (dt,i) = min((tau,i) for i,tau in enumerate(dt_list))
    t += dt
    arrivals += (i, t)
```

i.e., you actually *do* generate separate interarrival times for all processes, but you do not need to "remember" the states of the processes. Note that the minimum of two independent exponentially-distributed random variables with rates r1 and r2 is itself exponentially distributed with rate r1+r2 (per http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-440-probability-and-random-variables-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT18_440S11_Lecture20.pdf), so this is actually quite similar to the previous code snippet.

Of the two methods I have given here, I think the first is better:

- The first is O( len(arrivals) * log(len(rates)) ) whereas the second is O( len(arrivals) * len(rates) )
- The first requires 2 random numbers from the underlying generator per arrival, whereas the second requires len(rates) random numbers per arrival.
- The first requires 1 evaluation of log (I assume this is how the exponential random variable is generated) per arrival, whereas the second requires O(len(rates)) evaluations of log per arrival.

Also, take all of the above Python syntax with a grain of salt (I have not run it, and I am rusty with Python), and eliminate temporary lists if you like. This is meant as "pseudocode" really; for a fast Monte Carlo simulation you'd probably use C++ (and/or CUDA) anyway.

I know you're probably well past the point of needing this answer, but I hope it can be helpful to others who find this post.